# Difference in request body in aws api gateway test and curl

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I'm trying to add a POST HTTP method to my AWS API Gateway. I'm using SAM framework with Python.

I find that there is a difference in the "body" of the response when it is generated from my desktop (curl or postman) and the AWS API Gateway 'TEST'

Right now, the "POST" command only prints the 'event' object received by the lambda_handler. (I'm using an object to store the event as you can see below)

```
def add(self):
    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(self._event)
    }
    return response
```

When I'm using the 'TEST' option of the API Gateway console, with the input:

```
{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}
```

I receive the following output:

```
{
 "body": "{\"username\":\"xyz\",\"password\":\"xyz\"}",
<the rest of the response>
}
```

However, when I'm sending the curl (or postman) request:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"   --request POST   --data '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' <aws api gateway link>
```

I get the following response:

```
{
"body": "eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Inh5eiIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoieHl6In0="
<the rest of the response>
}
```

Why do you think there is a difference between the two tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curl and Postman seem to be automatically Base64 encoding your Authentication credentials.

The responses are the same. The latter response is a Base64-encoded token of the first response.

Comment: Great Catch! I added `x-amazon-apigateway-binary-media-types: */*` to the yml file which apparently caused to be decoded. Thanks! It is a little misleading that the 'API Gateway' test doesn't present the body decoded as well